# Does Radon Gas Worsen The Effectiveness or Usability of Consumer Grade Wireless Electronics?

Tags: electronics, radioactivity

Some notes:

- I don't have a Geiger counter.
- The wireless headset is near my computer.
- It goes in and out of the audio signal.
- The audio has audible cracks that sound like a Geiger counter.
- My family did some digging in and around our mobile home.

Some research I've done:

- Ionizing radiation creates electron-hole pairs in the electronics, changing the transistor parameters and eventually destroying them.
- Ionizing radiation can also cause leakage currents between circuits.

Some hypothesies:

- It could be that the radon gas is being funneled in by our A/C, and that this is causing the effects to go in and out.

Comment: If you have enough radon around to damage your electronics, I think you should not be alive anymore. Cracks in the audio may have a more probable origin in electric sparks.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing in the first place whether or not there actually *is* any radon at all in your house, there is no way you can conclude anything at all about whether the cracks and pops you claim to hear are being caused by radioactivity.